# Dropdown Data is overlapped with some default elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown as below:

```
<div class="col s4">
            <label class="control-label flabels">Name</label>
            <div class="asteRisk">*</div>
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                <div id="FLevelRow" class="row">
                    <div class="select-wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="multipleSelection" id="TaskName">
                                <select required class="dynamic_Time form-control" id="TaskSKAdd">
                                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="overSelect"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and I have written below ajax success method in `Js` file to append ajax response to this dropdown options.

```
success: function (response) {           
        console.log("Lookupresponse", response)
        for (var application of response) {
            var value = application.NAME.toLowerCase();
            $('#TaskName .dynamic_Time')
                .append(`<option value="${application.id}" name="${value}">${value} </option>`)
        }          
    },
```

But while running this code, by default some extra html elements and a select option appears before the above appended options and hence it hides appended options with ajax data from the dropdown list as shown in the below image. Because of that, original content are not visible while clicking on the dropdown. There is no error in the console also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any reasons for C# tag?

Comment: But there is no C# code ... ajax stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML

Comment: Please tag based on what the *question* is about.   eg don't tag "keyboard" because "I typed in the code with a keyboard"

Comment: `class='select-wrapper'` makes it look like you have a ... select wrapper.   ie something like [tag:select2] (but not select2) that wraps the `select` and makes an HTML drop down, typically using styled ul/li (as also shown in your code).   Hard to tell exactly which select wrapper it is given the vague/generic class name.   You'll need to call the wrapper's API to update the UI when changes are made to the underlying (hidden) `select`

Comment: You have some other script that is skinning the select tag, hence the resulting <ul>. This script is running before you inject the <option>s from the ajax call. Check which library is being used to skin the selects and with that check their docs to see how to update the <options> in the select. I would also double check the html elements, looks like a copy paste of a skinned select but that should be handled by the skinning library so some elements might end up duplicated. Let us know which library it is to help you further.